# When will chrome devtool's network time change to a smaller value after the request finish

Tags: http, google-chrome-devtools, web-performance

Recently I encountered an issue where a network request's time can change in devtool after it finishes.

At the very beginning we have the first request recorded as usual:

[image]

As the page goes on load, this request cost 1.1s in devtool's network panel and say on this time value for a while:

[image]

After this request is finished, its time changes to 286ms suddenly without any solid reason:

[image]

I can't figure out why this time changes and why it would cause so much time.

Can notic `transfer-encoding: chunked` in response header but not sure this is a key factor to this behavior.

Comment: Have you found the cause for this? I came across a similar issue and i guess it could be due to app completely reloading.

Comment: I've seen the same thing on an XHR request where it will show something like 4.02 seconds, then update when the request is complete to 1.97 seconds.  I don't see anything like the initial time in the waterfall UI, but in the HAR the "blocked" time is close.  Maybe it is removing that from the total?